# Downgrade php 8.0.10 to 8.0.0

Tags: 18.04, php, downgrade

Im tring to download Yii2 framework. The is error: require php >=5.6.0 <8.0 -> your php version (8.0.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
How can i downgrade version of php?
Thanks in advance for the answers

Comment: OS - ubuntu 18.04.5

Answer (score 1):

It'll first delete the current php version 8.0.10 and then install your required version.

```
sudo apt-get purge php8.*
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.4
```

you can change "sudo apt-get install php7.4" according to your need. Like, "sudo apt-get install php5.6" will install the version 5.6,
Then you can check the version using

```
php -v
```

(Showed php7.4 because the error message is <8.0, not <=8.0, so, 8.0.0 will give the error message as well)

Comment: 7.4 is the last version before 8.0

Comment: Sorry, i checked the versions after submitting the initial answer.